# What happened to Ben Mitchell's Glasses?

Tags: character, costume, eastenders

As seen below, previous actors of Ben Mitchell have always worn glasses. However, when Max Bowden was recast, these disappeared. Has there been any mention of this / any reason why the actor doesn't wear glasses whilst acting?

[image: 1]

Comment: Contact lenes? Laser eye surgery?

Comment: Also, it's probably OT, but this must be approaching a record for the most people to play the same part!

Comment: @Darren - I doubt it's even in the top hundred. There are twelve different Harry Potter actors and more then ten Captain Picards if you include flashbacks.

Comment: @Valorum with caveats of course (as part of a regular, consecutive run. Not flash-backs, "body-swap" stories etc). And not Dr Who, whose each incarnation is arguably a different character.

Comment: Although this was on the assumption we were talking about yet another new actor, but it seems the incumbent has been in place since 2019. I don't watch it myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was addressed in a blink-and-you'll-miss-it scene just after his arrival back in Albert Square.

> ... the explanation for the lack of specs is a pretty simple one which Ben himself addressed on Tuesday night’s episode.
>
> As Ben said: ‘Feeling happy to see my family, his friend Jay jokingly quipped: **‘Surprised you can see your family without your glasses on.’**
>
> To which Ben replied: **‘Contacts, you idiot.'**
>
> <sub><sup>METRO news: https://metro.co.uk/2019/04/04/whats-happened-to-bens-glasses-and-hearing-aid-as-he-returns-to-eastenders-9105704/</sup></sub>